# Can I configure access token TTL in spring auth server application.yml?

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I need to change access token TTL in spring authorization server without writing additional code. It must be as simple as adding a line in application.yml The problem is what line and does such line exist.

I tried to add `access-token-validity-seconds` as

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      authorizationserver:
        client:
          qbr-client:
            registration:
              client-id: "${QBR_CLIENT_ID}"
              client-secret: "{noop}${QBR_CLIENT_SECRET}"
              client-authentication-methods:
                - "client_secret_basic"
              authorization-grant-types:
                - "client_credentials"
              access-token-validity-seconds: 3600
```

It does not work
Please, tell me if such line exists.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody looking for the answer - this works

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      authorizationserver:
        client:
          qbr-client:
            registration:
              client-id: "${QBR_CLIENT_ID}"
              client-secret: "{noop}${QBR_CLIENT_SECRET}"
              client-authentication-methods:
                - "client_secret_basic"
              authorization-grant-types:
                - "client_credentials"
            token:
              access-token-time-to-live: 3600000
```